# Differential Equation: $f'(x) = f(x) (1-f(x))$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm lost on the following problem:

Find the function f(x) such that f'(x) = f(x)(1-f(x)) and f(0) = 1/7. (Use f for f(x) in your equation).

I'm assuming I can write this as:

$$ \frac {df}{dx} = f(1-f) $$

And rearrange it such that:

$$ \frac{df}{f-f^2} = dx $$

And take the integrals of both sides so:

$$ lnf-ln(f-1) = x $$

BUT when I try to solve for f (taking e on both sides), I get:

$$ f - (f-1) = e^x $$
Which cancels out my "f". What am I doing wrong, and how should I approach the question?

Comment: You badly took the logarithm my friend! First write the left hand-side as $$\ln\Big(\frac{f}{f-1}\Big)$$ and then take the exponential.

Comment: Further more, you should have used the initial condition when taking the integral. Please try to correct it yourself and come back with your solution.

Comment: As others have said, don't forget the +C, and $e^{\ln{f} - \ln{(f-1)}} = \frac{f}{f-1}$. So you should get $\frac{f}{f-1} = Ce^x$.

Comment: So based on everyone's comments, I've got:

$$ \frac{f}{f-1} = e^x + C $$

Now I'm not sure how I'm supposed to isolate f. 

I'm assuming that once I've found f = [function], I can substitute for x = 0 and f = 1/7 in order to find C.

Answer (score 4):

maybe   $a^{b-c}\neq a^b - a^c$

Answer (score 2):

You should get

$$\log(\dfrac{f}{f-1}) = x$$

so that

$$f/(f-1) = e^x$$

so that

$$f = fe^x - e^x$$

so that

$$f = -e^x/(1-e^x) = \dfrac{e^x}{e^x-1}.$$

You made an algebraic error.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you're getting 

$$ f = \frac {e^x}{e^x-1} $$ from $$ f = fe^x-e^x $$

Comment: By elementary algebra.... Subtract $ fe^x $ from both sides, factorize the resulting LHS as $ f (1-e^x) $ and divide both sides through by $(1- e^x) $.

Answer (score 1):

What after **BUT** is wrong, namely
$$\ln f-\ln(1-f)=x$$does not imply $$f-(f-1)=e^x$$ BUT $$\ln f-\ln(1-f)=x\implies \ln(\frac{f}{1-f})=x$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer I got was:

$$ f = \frac {e^x}{C + e^x} $$

I mostly just guessed to find it, as I wasn't sure how to integrate the constant "C" into the solution. If someone could tell me, that would be awesome.